# Insert a control on the input values in this code

Tags: android

```
button = new Button (this);
button.setText("Insert values");
tableLayout.addView(secondo);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < r1; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < c1;  j++){
                //insert values from a matrix of edittext in array      
                array[t] = Integer.parseInt(values[i][j].getText().toString()); 
                t++;
            }
        }
    }       
});
```

I want to put in this code a control on the input of values by edittext, that show me an alert when the values in input is incorrect, because now the app crash when the input is incorrect. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try {
    for(int i = 0; i < r1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < c1;  j++){
            //insert values from a matrix of edittext in array
            array[t] = Integer.parseInt(values[i][j].getText().toString());
            t++;
        }
    }
}
catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivityClassName.this);
    builder.setTitle("Error");
    builder.setMessage("Wrong input format"); 
    builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
    builder.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to deal with it:

One you wont allow user to type in wrong input. Setting [input type for EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) will help if your input is one of the pre-defined types. If that is not sufficient, you can try [TextView's addTextChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29). Since `EditText` extends `TextView` you can use it on `EditText` too.

Second if you want to check the validity after the user presses the button, then you have to figure out the input is invalide like by catching the `NumberFormatException` etc. Then you can show a dialog to user in the `onClick` handler by calling [showDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#showDialog%28int%29) if you are not using fragments and [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) if you are using fragments.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
final EditText enterABC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userinput_no_edittext);
Button okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.userinput_ok_button);
okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// read from EditText when user presses OK button
    mVariable = enterABC.getText().toString();
 }
});
```

Leave a comment for me if you have any problem following the code.

Comment: I had thought of a try {} catch {}, and a alertdialog to show me an error message when the input is incorrect, and that allows me to correct the entry

Comment: I think you have all the answers you were looking for. Happy Coding.